# Want to open datepicker calendar as a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to open datepicker calendar as a dialog so that when the calendar is opened, all other form elements don't get focus. Is there any default setting for datepicker thrrough which it can be opened as a dialog?

Comment: are you using the JQueryUI framework?

Comment: You can try disable all other input when calendar is show, then re-enable them when it close

Comment: yes I'm using JQueryUI framework

Comment: @Trinh Hoang Nhu I tried this also. but the button over which the calender opens on the page, gets focus in disable state also. This is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $('<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 2000px; height: 2000px; z-index: 1002; left:0; top:0; position :fixed"></div>').insertBefore('#ui-datepicker-div');
            setTimeout(function(){$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 199999);},2);

        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

            $('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
        }

    });
});
```

this is a little hack, the idea is basically put a overlay (the one use on jquery dialog modal) under a datepicker

Comment: I just tried this but now I won't be able to choose any day. not even able to choose month or year.

Comment: I found the problem of z-index of datepicker dialog

Answer (score 2):

You can use a fancybox, which in turn can contain a text input and calendar control. On close of fancybox, you can pass on the date value to any text input or label on the parent page.